# Integrating React to an existing ASP.NET Core MVC web app

Tags: sql-server, reactjs, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-3.0

I have an existing ASP.NET Core MVC web app that I created with .NET Core 3.0.

I want some parts of my application to be single page app - so how do I integrate React into an existing ASP.NET Core MVC web app? Please help

Comment: https://reactjs.net/tutorials/aspnetcore.html?

Comment: I’ve seen the ReactJS.net integration wanted to configure it with webpack is this possible? And how will I render data to my react views